# Logging into website and scraping data

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, .aspxauth

The website I am trying to log in to is https://realitysportsonline.com/RSOLanding.aspx. I can't seem to get the login to work since the process is a little different to a typical site that has a login specific page. I haven't got any errors, but the log in action doesn't work, which then causes the main to redirect to the homepage.

```
import requests
url = "https://realitysportsonline.com/RSOLanding.aspx"
main = "https://realitysportsonline.com/SetLineup_Contracts.aspx?leagueId=3000&viewingTeam=1"
data = {"username": "", "password": "", "vc_btn3 vc_btn3-size-md vc_btn3-shape-rounded vc_btn3-style-3d vc_btn3-color-danger" : "Log In"}
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36',
          'Referer':  'https://realitysportsonline.com/RSOLanding.aspx', 
          'Host':  'realitysportsonline.com',
          'Connection':   'keep-alive',
          'Accept-Language':    'en-US,en;q=0.5',
          'Accept-Encoding':    'gzip, deflate, br',
          'Accept':  'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8'}

s = requests.session()
s.get(url)
r = s.post(url, data, headers=header)

page = requests.get(main)
```

Comment: In what way does the code you've provided not work? Does it produce an error? If so, please edit your question to mention that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you create a session and assuming your `POST` request worked, you then request an authorised page without using your previously created session.

You need to  make the request with the `s` object you created like so:
`page = s.get(main)`

However, there were also a few issues with your `POST` request. You were making a request to the home page instead of the `/Login` route. You were also missing the `Content-Type` header.

```
import requests

url = "https://realitysportsonline.com/Services/AccountService.svc/Login"
main = "https://realitysportsonline.com/LeagueSetup.aspx?create=true"
payload = {"username":"","password":""}
headers = {
    'Content-Type': "text/json",
    'Cache-Control': "no-cache"
}

s = requests.session()
response = s.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
page = s.get(main)
```

PS your `main` request url redirects to the homepage, even with a valid session (at least for me).